# Postgres - Get all dates between start_date and end_date

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have two dates, say start_date = '2018-04-01' and end_date '2018-04-30', how would I get it to output every date in between including those dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select g.dte
from generate_series('2018-04-01'::timestamp, '2018-04-30'::timestamp, interval '1 day') g(dte);
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/CFYEA15860).  I took the liberty of fixing the last date in April.